# Cannot access webmasters.dat: No such file or directory

Tags: google-api, google-oauth, google-api-python-client, google-search-api, google-apis-explorer

i am trying to access google search console api - tried the sample [https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-python-client/blob/master/samples/searchconsole/search_analytics_api_sample.py][1]

i followed the instructions:

> 1) Install the Google Python client library, as shown at
>   https://developers.google.com/webmaster-tools/v3/libraries. 
>   2) Sign up for a new project in the Google APIs console at
>   https://code.google.com/apis/console. 
>   3) Register the project to use
>   OAuth2.0 for installed applications.
>   4) Copy your client ID, client
>   secret, and redirect URL into the client_secrets.json file included in
>   this package. 
>   5) Run the app in the command-line as shown below.
>   Sample usage:   $ python search_analytics_api_sample.py
>   'https://www.example.com/' '2015-05-01' '2015-05-30'

of course for my site and newer dates..

recieved in cmd the warning:

> \AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\oauth2client_helpers.py:255:
>   UserWarning: Cannot access webmasters.dat: No such file or directory

in the window opened in the browser got the message:

> Error 400: redirect_uri_mismatch The redirect URI in the request,
>   http://localhost:8080/, does not match the ones authorized for the
>   OAuth client. To update the authorized redirect URIs, visit:
>   https://console.developers.google.com/apis/credentials/oauthclient/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com?project=xxxxxxxxxxxx

i configured the redirect URI as http://localhost:8080/ but still the same

appreciate any help thanks